# Raspberry PI 4+Ubuntu Mate works with IR remote shield?

Tags: drivers, kernel, raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate, devices

I have already tested my IR remote shield in a Raspberry PI 3B and works ok (with Raspbian + Lirc). Now I want to make it run in my raspberry pi 4 with Ubuntu Mate installed. Here is my uname -a :

Linux anacelia-raspi 5.4.0-1032-raspi #35-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Mar 19 20:56:57 UTC 2021 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux

I tried with lirc and gpio-ir but neither of both works! Can you send me a suggestion ?
Thanks a lot!
Regards, Ana

Comment: Hi, I'm still trying to resolve this issue, I don't know which module to load /etc/modules/ or if I have to configure /boot/config.txt with dtoverlay or whatever guide I have to follow. The information available is confusing, I don't know if I have to use lirc tool or the native kernel ir support.  Nobody has  tested it ? Thanks!